# How to render form fields in Symfony dynamically (Forms generator)

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Im writing simple forms generator where user can add various types of fields.

For example (text,text,email,file,checkbox). 
[image]

Then i put data about those inputs to DB ( name, placeholder, default value etc).

How to generate symfony form without knowing what types of inputs and amount will it have?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you need Form Events for this purpose http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Comment: you can see how work this bundle:
https://github.com/Kunstmaan/KunstmaanFormBundle

There is a functionality like you need, but more advanced.

Look on entity/FormSubmission